# Как создать таблицу на html и вставить туда числа переменных javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var yndanurArq = 0;
var yndanurVajarq = 0;

var index = prompt("Ներմուծել ապրանքի տեսականու քանակը");
index = parseFloat(index);
for (let index1 = 0;index1 < index; index1++) {
    var anvanumy = prompt("Ներմուծել " + index1 + " ապրանքի անվանումը");
    
    var giny = prompt("Ներմուծել " + anvanumy +"ի գինը(առք)");
    giny = parseFloat(giny);
    var qanaky = prompt("Ներմուծել " + anvanumy+"ի քանակը");
    qanaky = parseFloat(qanaky);
    var vajarqiGiny = prompt("Ներմուծել " + anvanumy +"ի գինը(վաճառք)");
    vajarqiGiny = parseFloat(vajarqiGiny);
    var amboxjArq = giny * qanaky;
    var amboxjVajarq = vajarqiGiny * qanaky;

         console.log(anvanumy +"ի համար ծախսված գումարը " + amboxjArq);
         console.log(anvanumy +"ի վաճառքից ստացված գումարը " + amboxjVajarq);
       
         yndanurArq =  yndanurArq + amboxjArq;//arq
         yndanurVajarq =  yndanurVajarq + amboxjVajarq; //vajarq


              
}
let ekamuty = yndanurVajarq - yndanurArq; 

alert("Ինչքան գումար է ծախսվել ամբողջ ապրանքի համար(առք)" + yndanurArq)
alert("Ինչքան գումար է ստացվել ամբողջ ապրանքի վաճառքից(վաճառք)" + yndanurVajarq)
alert("Եկամուտը" + ekamuty)
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stayle.css">
    <title>Веб</title>
    </head>
   <body>
  
   </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос и пример не много отличаются, по єтому я отвечаю на вопрос как создать таблицу в HTML и наполнить ее данными.

---

Пример кода:

```js
function addTable() {
    let myTableDiv = document.getElementById("metric_results")
    let table = document.createElement('TABLE')
    let tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

    table.border = '1'
    table.appendChild(tableBody);

    let heading = new Array();
    heading[0] = "Команда"
    heading[1] = "Город"
    heading[2] = "Год основания"
    heading[3] = "Побед в чемпионате СССР"


    let stock = new Array()
    let topTeams = [
 {name: 'Динамо', city: 'Киев', year: '1927', champion: 13},
 {name: 'Динамо', city: 'Минск', year: '1927', champion: 1},
 {name: 'Динамо', city: 'Москва', year: '1923', champion: 11},
 {name: 'Динамо', city: 'Тбилиси', year: '1925', champion: 2},
 {name: 'Динамо', city: 'Ленинград', year: '1922', champion: 0}];
    

     for(let i = 0; i < topTeams.length; i++){
        let temp = [];
        temp.push(topTeams[i].name);
        temp.push(topTeams[i].city);
        temp.push(topTeams[i].year);
        temp.push(topTeams[i].champion);
        stock.push(temp);
     }

    //TABLE COLUMNS
    let tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    for (let i = 0; i < heading.length; i++) {
        let th = document.createElement('TH')
        th.width = '75';
        th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(heading[i]));
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    //TABLE ROWS
    for (let i = 0; i < stock.length; i++) {
        let tr = document.createElement('TR');
        for (j = 0; j < stock[i].length; j++) {
            let td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stock[i][j]));
            tr.appendChild(td)
        }
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    }  
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table)
}
```

```html
<div id="metric_results">
    <input type="button" id="create" value="Click here" onclick="Javascript:addTable()">
</div>
```

Еще один способ уменьшить количество строк кода, заменить цикл for приведенным ниже кодом.

```
let keys = Object.keys(topProductList[0]);
 for(let i = 0; i < topProductList.length; i++){
   let temp = [];
   for(let key in keys){
    temp.push(topProductList[i][keys[key]]);
   }
   stock.push(temp);
 }
```